# Windows batch start command and ECHO on completion and close the cmd's window

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-task-scheduler

I'm trying to schedule a script to run on windows. The triggering part works fine. The important part of my script looks like:

```
start C:\staging-script -arg1 arg -arg2 arg & ECHO "Did staging"
start C:\prod-script -arg1 arg -arg2 arg & ECHO "Did prod"
```

When I run it from cmd.exe, two more cmd windows are opened, both execute the script, and then the windows don't close. When I try to use Windows scheduler for this, it fails because the "resource is still in use"

Additionally, the ECHOs happen in the original window (which is where they should happen) but happen right away, not when the start task completes.

Comment: the windows don't close because of something in the scripts maybe? a pause? can you show us the scripts? and the "echo after process started by start in the parent window" seems to be a lost cause.

Comment: The command seems to quit. The new cmd windows show `C:\>` and that prompt works.

Comment: `start "" cmd /C your-script -args`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`start` creates an independent process. Once the process is started, the message is produced and the next line executed.

If you want the two `start`ed processes to execute in parallel and you're only bothered by those processes' windows' not closing, insert

```
exit
```

in the scripts `start`ed

If you want to execute the processes serially, that is complete process1 before producing the message and starting process2, then `CALL` the batches, don't `start` them.

Comment: I cant modify the scripts. Is there a good way to have a multiline, inline-ed script? Like can I do
`start (MYSCRIPT & exit)` or something like that?

Comment: How about starting a 2-line script : `call C:\staging-script -arg1 arg -arg2 arg ` / `exit`. Remember that two `start`ed scripts will execute in parallel, so if one is using resources that the other requires, then they will interfere with each other, so you'd need to ensure that the second doesn't start before the first is finished, which would make the choice to be "change the `start` to `call`

Comment: Can that be done inline? Or does it need to be a different file?

Comment: Different file.

Answer (score 0):

try adding exit to the end of each script the windows execute.